# Rotativa Header sometimes not displaying

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, rotativa

I got problem with Rotativa. I print tables and i want to have header and footer on every printed page. The problem is that sometimes its working, sometimes it doesn't. Even if pdf doesn't include header it still has same size as pdf with header. Any solutions? :/ Here is how I generate pdf

```
string footer = this.Url.Action("PDFGeneratorFooter", "Home", null, this.Request.Url.Scheme);
            string header = this.Url.Action("PDFGeneratorHeader", "Home", new { number = number }, this.Request.Url.Scheme);

            var pdfFile = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("OffersToPdf", movm)
            {
                PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
                FileName = "firstPdf.pdf",
                CustomSwitches = " --footer-html \"" + footer + "\" " + "--header-html \"" + header + "\""
            };

            byte[] applicationPDFData = pdfFile.BuildPdf(ControllerContext);

            path = Path.Combine(path, pdfFile.FileName);
            var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            fileStream.Write(applicationPDFData, 0, applicationPDFData.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
```

Here is my Header View

```
<body style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important;">
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="background-color: black;">
        <img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. Setting you header/footer files as plain .html is NOT an option since you want to be able to pass your model to the Views.

Here are some things you can do that worked for me:

1. Use Rotativa version 1.6.4, instead of the latest.
2. As said in [this post](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2083#issuecomment-95945226), if your header file includes any styles or javascript, sometimes the problem is solved by putting them **inside** the header file, instead of having them as external .js/.css files.
3. If your header has any javascript, increase the CustomSwitches option **--javascript-delay** value to give javascript time to load properly. Ex. `--javascript-delay 400` (default is 200ms).
4. Be sure to put the `<!DOCTYPE html>` markup at the very top of each file, including the file with the content, in this case your OffersToPdf file.

Also, play with the Rotativa **PageMargins** option so there is enough space on the PDF for your header and footer to fit.

```
var pdfFile = new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("OffersToPdf", movm)
    {
        PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
        FileName = "firstPdf.pdf",
        PageMargins = new Rotativa.Options.Margins(25, 5, 35, 5)
        CustomSwitches = " --footer-html \"" + footer + "\" " + "--header-html \"" + header + "\""
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you still need this, but anyway... Since you don't have any layout, the header don't have a html format. And you need to set the DOCTYPE (). The better way to do it is by giving a normal .html file as the header. I give you this link i've found as an example:
[Add footer and header to pdf in rotativa](https://bhavdiptala.blogspot.cl/2016/05/displaying-headers-and-footers-in-pdf.html)

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems using the header next to the footer with the .cshtml files, I could only use either the header or footer, until I changed both by html.

In this case use two files with the .html extension that works.